# React native or expo - do you know a way to push a notification even when the app is dead or have not been opened?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

Is it possible to implement a push notification when the app haven't been opened, in the case of a messaging app, when the user gets a message, i want a notification to be pushed to his device

Comment: The push notification system works like already that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Expo's [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/overview/) of push notifications, also [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) for barebone react native applications, for that you'll need to use [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/).

Comment: just a quick question, does foreground means when the app has been opened but its still in the task manager, and background means that the app isn't even open ?

Comment: Background is when the app is running but it's on the task manager, and the foreground is when the app is running and the user is actually using it. However push notifications are sent even when the app is completely closed if that is what you're looking for

Comment: yes that's what i'm looking for, thank you so much !